# Visual Studio 2010 is creating a static library against my will

Tags: visual-studio-2010, static-libraries

I recently inherited a project which I've cleaned up and finished.  However, there is one annoying issue that is just bugging the heck out of me.  Whenever I build it, it creates a static library (*.lib + *.exp files) alongside the *.exe.  The *.lib file is unnecessary.  I can't for the life of me find where in the settings to turn this off.  It doesn't hurt anything to build it, it's just annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and since I'm a very pedantic person, I mind. So I used

```
dumpbin /EXPORTS the_naughty_file.lib
```

On the unwanted .lib file, and it reveals:

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 9.00.21022.08
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Dump of file E:\my-projects\Robotics\SLAM_plus_plus\bin\Release\SLAM_plus_plus6.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

     Exports

       ordinal    name

                  ??4_Init_locks@std@@QAEAAV01@ABV01@@Z (public: class std::_Init_locks & __thiscall std::_Init_locks::operator=(class std::_Init_locks const &))

  Summary

      DB .debug$S
      14 .idata$2
      14 .idata$3
       4 .idata$4
       4 .idata$5
      14 .idata$6
```

And after a while of googling, I found a [post](http://www.windows-api.com/microsoft/VC-Language/29218627/new-in-stdafxh-and-stdnothrow-causes-export-from-exe.aspx), explaining this is an automatically generated function, which is only generated when using dynamically-linked runtime library (static doesn't do that).

To fix the problem, either go to **Project Properties** > **C ++** > **Preprocessor**, and add:

```
_STATIC_CPPLIB
```

Or go to **Project Properties** > **C ++** > **Code Generation** and change Runtime Library to **Multithreaded (MT)**.

The annoying files are now gone, yay :). Tested in Visual Studio 2008, though. But if it doesn't work, just use dumpbin /EXPORTS on the .lib to trace exports and post them here.

Answer (score 0):

Either the project is designated as a static library or there is a project in the solution that is a static library.

Comment: There is only one project in the solution and as far as I can tell it's not a static library.  The "Configuration Type" is "Application (.exe)" and the "Target Extension" is ".exe".  These are under [Project] Property Pages > Configuration Properties > General. Is there somewhere else I should look?